# Query to Select Specific Fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection

like this about 1000 piece of data

```
> db.LOOKFOR.find().limit(5)

{ "_id" : ObjectId("594b7210eefb31d26983c1b8"), "detail" : "{'type': 'csv', 'size': '43','context':none"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("594b7210eefb31d26983c1b9"), "detail" : "{'type': 'jpg', 'size': '51','context':none"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("594b7210eefb31d26983c1ba"), "detail" : "{'type': 'csv', 'size': '23','context':none"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("594b7210eefb31d26983c1bb"), "detail" : "{'type': 'xml', 'size': '80','context':none"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("594b7210eefb31d26983c1bc"), "detail" : "{'type': 'csv', 'size': '32.12,'context':none"}
```

above this data is limit five,  how can I query all type >> detail of the type and not display others

(sorry,English is not my mother tongue)

Comment: This is [in the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-specific-fields-in-embedded-documents) `db.LOOKFOR.find({},{ "detail.type": 1 })`

Comment: Also see ["Dot Notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) in the documentation, which explains the syntax for addressing nested content.